# How to make a measure that counts summarized values that are over certain number

Tags: powerbi, dax, relation, measure, m

That title was kinda hard to phrase but I'll try to explain myself a bit better.

So I have a few tables where I have a few relations going:

[image: Relations between T1 <-> T2 <-> T3 <-> T4]

`Table 1` (`T1` in picture) has a column that has `ID`. The `ID` can be in format such as: `id1, id2, id3` or `id1` or `id1;id2;id3`.

The `T4` is the table with the column that I want to relate the `ID` column from `T1` table. For that purpose, I have created a distinct version of the `ID` column in `T2` table from `T1` (it removes duplicate values).

`T1` is related to `T2` with a many-to-one relation. From `T2` I have created `T3` as a duplicate where the `ID` column is split to rows by delimiters `,` and `;` and related to `T2` with a one-to-many relation. This creates the table where ID values are separated but still related to the `T1` via relation to `T2`.

Finally, the relation from `T3`'s split `ID` column is formed to `T4` ID column via many to one relation.

Now the real question I have is that how can I count how many `ID`s in `T4` have more than 5 related rows in `T1` table?

I have placed the `ID` from `T4` and the count of `T1`'s `ID` on a table visual which shows the rows, but I don't really know how I can count the ones that surpass that certain requirement.

[image: Picture of the ID from T4 with the Count of <code>ID</code> from T1]

The result I want is somewhat like:

> IDs with more than 5 related rows : *350*
>
> IDs with related rows : *474*

Answer (score 0):

1st of, i'am not 100% sure I understood your IDs format, but this might be worth a try.

Create a calculated column as:

countT1Rows =
VAR currentId = T4['id']
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( T1, T1['id'] = currentId ) )

The formula counts for every row in T4 the number for rows in T1, which have identical ID.
Than you can use slicer to filter only rows with 5 or more related rows. Or you could wrap it in IF clause.